# Is there a tight lower bound for the expectation of the product of two positive valued random variables?

Tags: pr.probability, probability-distributions, inequalities, expectation, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

Let $X,Y$ be two (dependent) random variables with $\mathbb{P}(X\ge 0)=\mathbb{P}(Y\ge 0)=1$.

> I want to find a tight lower bound of $\mathbb{E}(XY)$ when $X,Y$ are non-negative, almost surely.

Note that one trivial lower bound is $0$. But I want to know if there is an elegant method in literature for finding a tight lower bound, which has information of only the individual moments of the random variables $X,Y$.

I realize that the following lower bound can be obtained simply by using Cauchy-Scwartz inequality $$\mathbb{E}(XY)\ge \mu_X\mu_Y-\sigma_X\sigma_Y,$$ where $\mu_X=\mathbb{E}X,\ \sigma_X^2=\mathrm{Var}(X)$, and similarly $\mu_Y,\sigma_Y$ defined for $Y$. However, I don't know that if $X,Y$ are non-negative, almost surely, then whether this lower bound is non-negative. A little bit of algebra shows that this claim is equivalent to the following claim $$\frac{\mu_X^2}{\mu_{X^2}}+\frac{\mu_Y^2}{\mu_{Y^2}}\ge 1.$$ However, when $X=Y$, this claim is equivalent to proving that $$\mu_X^2\ge \frac{\mu_{X^2}}{2},$$ which, however, is false in general because Holder's inequality implies that $|\mu_X|\le \frac{\sqrt{\mu_{X^2}}}{\sqrt{2}}$. Any ideas how I can proceed? Thanks in advance.

Comment: In what terms do you want the tight lower to be?

Comment: I want the lower bound to be at least non-negative and to be equal to $\mu_{X^2}$ when $X=Y$.

Comment: "I want the lower bound to be at least non-negative and to be equal to $\mu_{x^2}$ when X=Y" I interpret X=Y as meaning that $X=Y$ in distribution, because, you are assuming no knowledge of the dependency between $X$ and $Y$, so you can not also assume $X=Y$ a.s. Given that interpretation, why would the quoted statement be true? For instance, let $X = 1$ or $3$, w.p. $1/2, 1/2$. Then $EX^2 = 9/2$. Then $Y = 4 - X$ has the same distribution as $X$, but $E(XY) = 3 \ne E(X^2)$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\newcommand{\de}{\delta}
\newcommand{\si}{\sigma}
\newcommand{\ep}{\varepsilon}$
Let us present the exact lower bound on $EXY$ in terms of $\mu_1:=\mu_X$, $\mu_2:=\mu_Y$, $\si_1:=\si_X$, $\si_2:=\si_Y$, as follows:

> The minimum of $EXY$ over all nonnegative random variables (r.v.'s) $X$ and $Y$ with prescribed positive values of $\mu_1$, $\mu_2$, $\si_1$, $\si_2$ is
> \begin{equation*}
>     \max(0,\mu_1\mu_2-\si_1\si_2).
> \tag{1}
> \end{equation*}

Indeed, by rescaling, without loss of generality
\begin{equation*}
    \mu_1=\mu_2=1.
\end{equation*}
Let
\begin{equation*}
r_j:=\frac1{1+\mu_j^2}
\end{equation*}
everywhere here $j\in\{1,2\}$. Observe that
\begin{equation*}
    \mu_1\mu_2-\si_1\si_2\le0\iff\si_1\si_2\ge1\iff r_1+r_2\le1. \tag{2}
\end{equation*}
Consider the two possible cases, according to this observation.

*Case 1: $r_1+r_2\le1$.* Then the bound in (1) is $0$. On the other hand, let $S:=\{0,1,2\}$ with the probability measure on $S$ assigning masses $1-r_1-r_2,r_1,r_2$ to the points $0,1,2$, respectively. Let r.v.'s $X$ and $Y$ be defined on $S$ as follows:
\begin{equation*}
    X(0)=X(2)=0,\ X(1)=v_1,\quad Y(0)=Y(1)=0,\ Y(2)=v_2. 
\end{equation*}
Then
\begin{equation*}
    EX=EY=1,\quad \operatorname{Var}X=\si_1^2,\quad \operatorname{Var}Y=\si_2^2,\quad EXY=E0=0. 
\end{equation*}
So the bound $(1)$ is exact in Case 1.

*Case 2: $r_1+r_2\ge1$.* Then the bound (1) follows by Cauchy--Schwarz:
\begin{equation*}
    EXY-\mu_1\mu_2=E(X-\mu_1)(Y-\mu_2)\ge-\si_1\si_2.  
\end{equation*}
By (2), in Case 2 we have $\si_1\si_2\le1$.
So we can find $p\in(0,1)$ such that for $q:=1-p$ we have
\begin{equation*}
    \si_2^2\le p/q\le1/\si_1^2. 
\end{equation*}
Let now $S:=\{0,1\}$ with the probability measure on $S$ assigning masses $q,p$ to the points $0,1$, respectively. Let r.v.'s $X$ and $Y$ be defined on $S$ as follows:
\begin{equation*}
    X(0)=1-\si_1\sqrt{p/q},\quad X(1)=1+\si_1\sqrt{q/p},
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
    Y(0)=1+\si_2\sqrt{p/q},\quad Y(1)=1-\si_2\sqrt{q/p}. 
\end{equation*}
Then $X,Y\ge0$,
\begin{equation*}
    EX=EY=1,\quad \operatorname{Var}X=\si_1^2,\quad \operatorname{Var}Y=\si_2^2,\quad EXY=1-\si_1\si_2. 
\end{equation*}
So the bound $(1)$ is exact in Case 2 as well. $\Box$

You were pretty close to this answer.

Comment: Great! Thanks for the full answer.